# Can all the CSS for HTML emails css go in the head?

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, mailchimp

I am using one of the MailChimp templates as a base for an email design, however I will not be using MailChimp to send the email.

The MailChimp template has around 330 lines of CSS in the head. Its beens a while since I last did HTML emails, but is this acceptable or do I have to use inline styles on the elements?

I wasn't sure if MailChimp had a script that turned all the styles into inline css, and if I had to do the same thing.

Comment: isn't that more to do with the mail client? They present emails and allow linking etc in different ways?

Comment: In my company we use a similar system to Mailchimp and I have to include the CSS rules in the elements.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`inline CSS` is the most preferred for email templates, because not all email clients support `CSS in head` section

Here is [**Guide to CSS support in email**](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Answer (score 4):

Gmail is now [rolling out support](https://litmus.com/blog/gmail-to-support-responsive-email-design?utm_campaign=gmail_updates&utm_source=pardot&utm_medium=email) for media queries and styles in the `head`.  Using [Campaign Monitor's Guide](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/), all the major clients now support styles in the `head`.  If you're wanting the broadest possible support it's probably safer to keep inlining styles, but if your users are all using the major clients it's now safe to start pulling the styles out.

Answer (score 2):

Inline Styles is the way go to achieve a consistent look and feel across all email clients.

Also have a look at: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/13/techniques-overcome-poor-css-support-email/

Comment: This link is broken, and couldn't find it on their site with a quick search (they should redirect old links).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great tool for taking an HTML-email document with styles in the header and moving them inline. Should save you a lot of time and effort.

http://premailer.dialect.ca/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which company you are using to send the email, certain companies, such as campaign monitor will automatically add your styles in the head to the corresponding elements marked with that class or ID. I would check whether the company provides that service before sending.

I would recommend using inline styling at all times, even if you are using a service that automatically adds it inline, just in case you ever decide to switch to another provider.

Generally the issues with using styles in the head come from gmail, hotmail and yahoo mail. These email clients tend to strip out the `<head>` tags. Some people claim that they are having positive results within these email clients with `<head>` styles, but if I were you I would play it safe and go inline.